# Why isn't there join relation in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I'm learning MongoDB these days. I find that MongoDB doesn't support join.
I just want to know why MongoDB choose to do this?

THANKS in advance..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Mongo - is not relational database and does not have physical relations and constraints.
2. Join kills scalability.

Usually denormalization replace sql join.

For example, on stackoverflow you have question and his owner, in mongodb it is normal case to denormilize owner data into question and avoid a join:

```
question
{
  _id,
  text,
  user_short :
  {
    id,
    full_name
  }
}
```

It is for sure lead to additional complexity on updates, but it give you significant performance improvements when you read the data. And for the most applications read is 95% and writes only 5% or even less.

Comment: 5Thanks~~ by the way, do 95% and 5% mean the degree of performance inprovement?

Comment: No, it is common percent of reads and writes for the most applications.

Comment: Redundancy and denormalization (Mongo/Mongo or Mongo/MySQL) can be easily implemented with frameworks like Doctrine 2. http://t.co/4OMetz4k

Answer (score 1):

Because MongoDb is a non relational database. Non-relational database does not support join it is by design.

Answer (score 1):

You can now do it in Mongo 3.2 using [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)

`$lookup` takes four arguments

`from`:     Specifies the collection in the same database to perform the join with. The from collection cannot be sharded.

`localField`: Specifies the field from the documents input to the $lookup stage. $lookup performs an equality match on the localField to the foreignField from the documents of the from collection.

`foreignField`: Specifies the field from the documents in the from collection.

`as`: Specifies the name of the new array field to add to the input documents. The new array field contains the matching documents from the from collection.

```
db.Foo.aggregate(
  {$unwind: "$bars"},
  {$lookup: {
    from:"bar",
    localField: "bars",
    foreignField: "_id",
    as: "bar"

   }},
   {$match: {
    "bar.testprop": true
   }}
)
```